# How do I make a part of my map off limit?

Tags: unity, 3d

I'm looking for a common way to make zones in my 3D map "off limit"? The kind of thing you see in eg Hitman games where NPCs will get suspicious if you step into certain areas. Will need several areas like this, corridors, rooms etc.

Is it just to create invisible collider objects that set an `offLimits` bool to true, or is there a preferable way?

Comment: If you have more than one use case, then please _tell us about it_. We can't come up with how to do it generically if you tell us only one case of what you need.

Comment: What would you like to happen when the player approaches this off-limits area? Or if they throw/shoot objects into it (if that's a thing in your game)? The more you can tell us about how your game should work, the better we can help you make it work that way.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it just to create invisible collider objects that set an offLimits bool to true?

It's even easier than that. You can just enable or disable the invisible wall colliders with [`gameObject.SetActive(false);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.SetActive.html). A Collider component on an inactive gameObject doesn't block anything.

But keep in mind that putting invisible walls in your game really breaks immersion. And when there is no way for the player to tell that an invisible wall was removed, they can really confuse the player about where they can and can't go. That makes them a last resort solution when you can not come up with a more plausible methods of restricting the player's freedom.

It's always better to find some diegetic obstacles which make sense in the context of your game world. Like a door being open or closed, a force-field being active or inactive, a drawbridge being down or up, an immovable and immortal NPC standing in the way or moving aside, and so on. But what method exactly is appropriate depends on the theme of your game.

Another alternative to hard invisible walls are "kill zones". When the player walks too far away from the playable area, you just kill them. An invincible enemy shows up and kills them in one hit, an invisible sniper shoots them, [the police shows up and arrest them for no reason](https://youtu.be/qRxwBb7ev1Y?t=79), the god of the game world smites them for abandoning their holy quest... whatever makes at least a bit of sense in the context of your game world.

Comment: I like your explanation of limiting the gameworld for a player in a proper way, though I wonder if the OP wanted to actually limit the world, or have NPC's (etc.) become aggressive when the player enters those areas, without having to 'make them angry' like in regular areas. (could also be my misunderstanding of the question.)